# I want to set the dimension dynamically from the layout file, is it possible to load the action bar size in dimension file?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

can i do like this ( I tested but crashed) is there any way to do like this.
--define dimension res

```
<dimen name="actionbarsize">@android:attr/actionBarSize</dimen>
```

--and use it like this

```
<LinearLayout 
 android:padingTop="@dimen/actionbarsize"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know It is impossible to change it dynamically.

But you can use a different apporach by changing the layout's paddings programatically.
This could be useful:

```
   int paddingTop = someMethod(); //or a static value       
   layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_id);
   LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)layout.getLayoutParams();
   params.setMargins(0, paddingTop, 0, 0); 
   layout.setLayoutParams(params);
```